# How do I populate an input type using a loop?

Tags: php

I have an array itemQuantities. It looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 ) 

foreach($_SESSION['itemQuantities'] as $key => $value) {
    echo "$value"; // gives 600
}
```

How do I populate this input class with default values taken from the array?

```
while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){       
    $tbl .= "<div class=\"col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4\">
                  <input class=\"form-control\" type=\"number\" min = \"0\" max = \"20\" value=\"$value\" id=\"num\" name=\"num[]\" required>
             </div>
}
```

I'm not sure how to handle the 2 loops. I keep getting **666** for my values as default input where I want **600** as the desired result.

Edit: Used a counter to solve my problem. Not sure why this was giving me so much trouble.

Comment: Welcome. How are the two loops related? It's hard to understand what you're trying to do there.

Comment: I have a column for inputs. In my example, I want to set the default values for those inputs 600 instead of 666. I'm not sure how to explain it, maybe this picture helps: https://i.imgur.com/GHYuBlz.png

Comment: So are these number actually coming from the row that you are fetching from the database? If they are what is the column called please? And I will rewrite my answer now I understand more whats really going on

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this? It is not totally clear from your question what you want to achieve.

```
foreach($_SESSION['itemQuantities'] as $key => $val) {
    $value .= $val;   // concatenate the values into a string
}

while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){       
    $tbl .= "<div class='col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4'>
              <input class='form-control' type='number' min='0' max='20' value='$value' id='num' name='num[]' required>
}
```

> It is a little strange that you are placing the value 600 into a fields with the `min="0" max="20"` attributes set to make that number illegal

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here that what you actually want is to display as many inputs as your query returns with default values from session array. You don't need two loops at all.

```
$idx = 0;
while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $value = $_SESSION['itemQuantities'][$idx] ?? 0;
    $tbl .= "<div class='col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4'>
              <input class='form-control' type='number' min='0' max='20' value='$value' id='num' name='num[]' required>";
    $idx++;
}
```